# "Very Similar" vs "Based On" for purpose of paper "narrative"

Tags: writing, writing-style

I was trying to solve a sub-problem as part of a greater problem for which I am writing a paper to propose a solution.

I'd been working on it for quite a while, when I had the thought that it could be transformed into a special case of one of the most famous and well researched problems in computer science.

I spent about a month doing that transformation while working on other things.
All the while though, I was thinking: "Someone else must have had this idea -- its too good not to have had." I didn't spend too much time searching for it, though, because I needed an implementation and not just an idea.
I finished up the method about a week ago, and ran it, and found it to work excellently.

Today, I finally found a paper where someone did have the idea.
Almost identical to mine (I'm really not at all displeased by this)
There are, as expected, a few differences, but nothing I can't explain in a few sentences.

So the question is, in my writeup I could say:

- **1a.** We extend the method of X, by adding ...
- **1b.** Our method is based on the method of X, but with the following variations...
- **2a.** The method we propose is very similar to the method of X, except ...
- **2b.** This method is similar to that of X, but developed independently. It has the following difference.

The options **2a/b**  are what actually occurred.
However, I wonder if I should not write instead **1a**, or **1b** because they provide a better narrative.  I've been told paper narrative is important.

I don't like the way 2b sounds, even if it is the most truthful. It sounds like I feel I have something to prove.

**Is it generally worth distorting the actual order of events, for a clean narrative?**

Answer (score 4):

In an ordinary scientific paper, nobody expects to get a narrative of your investigation, but rather a clear explanation of how the ideas fit together.  In fact, [it has been argued that success in science is precisely defined by the separation of statements from the circumstances of their creation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laboratory_Life#The_Construction_of_a_Fact:_The_Case_of_TRF.28H.29).

I would thus argue that you should no more feel obligated to tell a reader that you invented an idea independently than that you invented it while riding a bicycle.  You may not have started by basing your method on the other method, but now that you know it exists, you can skip all sorts of argumentation and verification by *changing the way you think about your method* in order to base it on the prior method and the work that has been done to establish it.

Thus, I would recommend using something like your statement 1a/1b.  That is not the history of events, but based on what you report, it appears to me to be a true and more accurate characterization of the *current* relationship between the concepts.  Since you discovered this prior method, you are no longer proposing a new method: instead, you are applying a slight variation on an existing method, as adapted to your circumstances, and should report that fact accordingly.